# Initializing an __m128 type from a 64-bit unsigned int

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics

The [`_mm_set_epi64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecz16x1z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and similar *_epi64 instructions seem to use and depend on `__m64` types. I want to initialize a variable of type `__m128` such that the upper 64 bits of it are 0, and the lower 64 bits of it are set to `x`, where `x` is of type `uint64_t` (or similar unsigned 64-bit type). What's the "right" way of doing so?

Preferably, this should be done in a compiler-independent manner.

Comment: Isn't this a microsoft-specific datatype?

Comment: @JohnDibling It's x86-specific. But definitely not MS-specific. All the major compilers (VS, GCC, ICC, Clang) support it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answser your question about how to load a 64-bit value into the lower 64-bits of a XMM register while zeroing the upper 64-bits  `_mm_loadl_epi64(&x)` [will do exactly what you want](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_int_load.htm).

In regards `to _mm_set_epi64` I said once that looking at the source code of Agner Fog's [Vector Class Library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) can answer 95% of the question on SSE/AVX on SO.  Agner implemented this (from the file vectori128.h) for multiple compilers and for 64-bit and 32-bit.  Note that the solution for MSVC 32-bit Agner says "this is inefficient, but other solutions are worse".  I guess that's what Mysticial means by "There isn't a good way to do it.".

```
Vec2q(int64_t i0, int64_t i1) {
#if defined (_MSC_VER) && ! defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
        // MS compiler has no _mm_set_epi64x in 32 bit mode
#if defined(__x86_64__)                                    // 64 bit mode
#if _MSC_VER < 1700
        __m128i x0 = _mm_cvtsi64_si128(i0);                // 64 bit load
        __m128i x1 = _mm_cvtsi64_si128(i1);                // 64 bit load
        xmm = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(x0,x1);                   // combine
#else
        xmm = _mm_set_epi64x(i1, i0);
#endif
#else   // MS compiler in 32-bit mode
        union {
            int64_t q[2];
            int32_t r[4];
        } u;
        u.q[0] = i0;  u.q[1] = i1;
        // this is inefficient, but other solutions are worse
        xmm = _mm_setr_epi32(u.r[0], u.r[1], u.r[2], u.r[3]);
#endif  // __x86_64__
#else   // Other compilers
        xmm = _mm_set_epi64x(i1, i0);
#endif
};
```

Answer (score 8):

The most common "standard" intrinsic for this is [_mm_set_epi64x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk2sdw0h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

For platforms that lack `_mm_set_epi64x` you can define a replacement macro like this:

```
#define _mm_set_epi64x(m0, m1) _mm_set_epi64(_m_from_int64(m0), _m_from_int64(m1))
```

Comment: And for anyone who cares about 32-bit anymore, this intrinsic only exists on x64. To target 32-bit, a different approach will be needed.

Comment: @Mysticial If you don't mind adding an answer on how to do that, that might be helpful for someone coming after me.

Comment: @Gideon There *isn't* a good way to do it. It's better to avoid these set intrinsics in the first place. The only place I find them acceptable would be compile-time constants - in which case, you just manually split the 64-bit integer into it's halves and use `_mm_set_epi32()`.

Comment: @Gideon, I posted an answser to your question.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to initialize a variable of type `__m128` ... where x is of type `uint64_t`

The intrinsic which takes the `uint64_t` is `_mm_set_epi64x` (as opposed to `_mm_set_epi64`, which takes a `__m64`).

I recently ran into the issue on Solaris. Sun Studio 12.3 and below lacks `_mm_set_epi64x`. It also lacks the work-arounds, like `_mm_cvtsi64_si128` and `_m_from_int64`.

Here's the hack I used, if interested. The other option was to disable SSE2, which was not too appealing (and it was 3x slower in benchmarks):

```
// Sun Studio 12.3 and earlier lack SSE2's _mm_set_epi64 and _mm_set_epi64x.
#if defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && (__SUNPRO_CC < 0x5130)
inline __m128i _mm_set_epi64x(const uint64_t a, const uint64_t b)
{
    union INT_128_64 {
        __m128i   v128;
        uint64_t  v64[2];
    };

    INT_128_64 v;
    v.v64[0] = b; v.v64[1] = a; 
    return v.v128;
}
#endif
```

I believe C++11 could do additional things to help the compiler and performance, like initialize a constant array:

```
const INT_128_64 v = {a,b};
return v.v128;
```

There's a big caveat... I believe there is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203) because a write occurs using the `v64` member of the union, and then read occurs using the `v128` member of the union. Testing under SunCC shows the compiler is doing the expected (but technically incorrect) thing.

I believe you can sidestep the undefined behavior using a `memcpy`, but that could crush performance. Also see Peter Cordes' answer and discussion at [How to swap two __m128i variables in C++03 given its an opaque type and an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38426740/608639).

The following may also be a good choice to avoid the undefined behavior from using the inactive union member. But I'm not sure about the punning.

```
INT_128_64 v;
v.v64[0] = b; v.v64[1] = a;
return *(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(v.v64));
```

---

***EDIT*** (three months later): Solaris and SunCC did not like the punning. It produced bad code for us, and we had to `memcpy` the value into `__m128i`. Unix, Linux, Windows, GCC, Clang, ICC, MSC were all OK. Only SunCC gave us trouble.

Comment: Type-punning with unions is preferable to pointer-casts.  They're both undefined behaviour according to the standard, but the union is safe with gcc at least.  The pointer-cast technique isn't safe with real compilers.  (except maybe with SIMD `__m128` types, which are defined with a may_alias attribute or something like that.  Hopefully SunCC defines it simlarly.)

Comment: It's worth trying memcpy if you're not sure that union-based type-punning is safe.  Some compilers are good about optimizing it away, but as you say, I showed that not all make acceptable code.  `memcpy` is AFAIK the only type-punning technique that is guaranteed to be portable by ISO C and C++, but union-based type-punning is widely used in real life as I understand it.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Looking at the SSE2 [`_mm_loadl_pi`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_loadl&expand=3079), it may be a suitable replacement. It allows the load of an unaligned 64-bit value. Using `_mm_loadl_pi` twice with an intermediate shift may avoid some of the theoretical problems.

Comment: If you actually want the compiler to emit load instructions, instead of `movd xmm0, eax` or `movq xmm0, rax` or something, then maybe.  But you should definitely not use it twice!  The intrinsics that look to most closely match the asm you'd want are `__m128i _mm_loadu_si64 (void const* mem_addr)` (to load the low 64 bits with `movq xmm0, m64`, zeroing the upper 64 of the xmm).  Or on compilers which don't support it, `_mm_loadl_epi64` which also says it compiles to a `movq` load.  Then `_mm_loadh_pi` to load the upper half with `movhps`.  Using a shift intrinsic would be silly.

Comment: Anyway, `movq` / `movl/h` could be good for a pair of non-adjacent 64-bit values.  BTW, no instructions have alignment requirements for operands of 64-bit or smaller; you don't need a special intrinsic for that.  I might also be ok to avoid a store-forwarding-failure stall on a pair of adjacent recently-written 64bit values, instead using `_mm_loadu_si128`.  (But pointer-casting for `_mm_loadu` should be aliasing-safe.  Possibly your cast version is actually safe, but I think I've seen an SO question where something like that didn't do what the OP wanted.)

Comment: update on my earlier comments: Union-based type punning is guaranteed to work in C99/C11, but *not* C++.  Casting `*(__m128i*)&v64[0]` should actually be safe, because __m128 types are special and are allowed to alias, unlike say `*(double *)&v64[0]`.  For example, gcc defines __m128i with `__attribute__((may_alias))`, unlike the internal v2qi native-vector type it's based on.  I've never liked `memcpy` for type punning, but maybe compilers are good enough at seeing through it that you don't get bad code in practice.  I forget if I've ever seen an example of it not optimizing away.